# NgrxStore and Angular - Use the async pipe massively or subscribe just once in the constructor

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am starting to look at ngrx Store and I see the convenience to use the Angular async pipe. At the same time I am not sure whether using the Angular async pipe massively is a good choice.

I make a simple example. Let's assume that in the same template I need to show different attributes of an object (e.g. a Person) which is retrieved from the Store.

A piece of template code could be

```
<div>{{(person$ | async).name}}</div>
<div>{{(person$ | async).address}}</div>
<div>{{(person$ | async).age}}</div>
```

while the component class constructor would have

```
export class MyComponent {
  person$: Observable<Person>;

  constructor(
    private store: Store<ApplicationState>
  ) {
      this.person$ = this.store.select(stateToCurrentPersonSelector);
  }
.....
.....
}
```

As far as I understand this code implies 3 subscriptions (made in the template via the async pipe) to the same Observable (`person$`).

An alternative would be to define 1 property (`person`) in MyComponent and to have only 1 subscription (in the constructor) that fills the property, such as

```
export class MyComponent {
  person: Person;

  constructor(
    private store: Store<ApplicationState>
  ) {
      this.store.select(stateToCurrentPersonSelector)
                .subscribe(person => this.person = person);
  }
.....
.....
}
```

while the template uses standard property binding (i.e. without the async pipe), such as

```
<div>{{person.name}}</div>
<div>{{person.address}}</div>
<div>{{person.age}}</div>
```

**Now the question**

Is there any difference in terms of performance between the 2 approaches? Is the massive use of async pipe (i.e. a massive use of subscriptions) going to affect the efficiency of the code?

Comment: You might want to consider using the async pipe in containers on inputs for 'dumb' components. See components and containers in the [`example-app`](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app/tree/master/src/app) and also [*Presentational and Container Components*](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0).

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Neither, you should compose your application as smart and presentation components.

**Advantages:**

- All buissness logic on the smart controller.
- Just one subscribe
- Reusability
- The presentation controller has only one responsibility, only to present data and does not know from where the data come from. (loosely coupled)

**Answering the last question:**

The massive use of async pipe will affect the efficiency, because it will subscribe to every async pipe. You can notice this more if you are calling a http service, because it will call the http request for each async pipe.

**Smart Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-my',
  template: `
      <app-person [person]="person$ | async"></app-person>
`,
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    person$: Observable<Person>;

    constructor(private store: Store<ApplicationState>) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.person$ = this.store.select(stateToCurrentPersonSelector);
    }

}
```

**Presentation Component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-person',
  template: `
    <div>{{person.name}}</div>
    <div>{{person.address}}</div>
    <div>{{person.age}}</div>
`,
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.css']
})
export class PersonComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() person: Person;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

For more info check:

- https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.u27zmzf25
- http://blog.angular-university.io/angular-2-smart-components-vs-presentation-components-whats-the-difference-when-to-use-each-and-why/

Comment: I appreciate the value of splitting smart and presentation components. It makes a lot of sense for all the reasons you have mentioned. If we just look at the 'code efficiency' side of the story, am I right in assuming that using one 'async pipe' and many 'property bindings' is more efficient than using 'many async pipes'? Thx in advance

Comment: Exactly the same information I wanted to ask for. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: good answer but how it would be useful when using child components with router?

Answer (score 22):

Another possibility is to use construction like this:

```
<div *ngIf="person$ | async as per">
    <div>{{ per.name }}</div>
    <div>{{ per.address }}</div>
    <div>{{ per.age }}</div>
<div>
```

Although for reusable bits of code its possibily better to use presentation component method.

Please note this works in angular 5, not sure about other versions.

Comment: I like this because it fuses the smart and presentational components into a single block of code.

I don't like this for the exact same reason.

:)

Comment: how do I access `per` in the controller? I guess now way?

Answer (score 14):

You can add ".share()" to the end of any observable declarations.  All of your async pipes on an observable will then share the same subscription:

```
this.name$ = Observable.create(observer => {
  console.log("Subscriber!", observer);
  return observer.next("john")
}).delay(2000).share();

this.httpget$ = http.get("https://api.github.com/").share();
```

Plunkr demonstrating:
https://embed.plnkr.co/HNuq1jUh3vyfR2IuIe4X/